# How to block a mouse click outside an open window?

Tags: vb.net

I have a main form in which I created 2 buttons.
The first "About" button displays the "About" window on the screen.
The second button "Close" closes the main form.
I would like, when the "About" window is displayed, that the user can not activate the buttons of the main form until the "About" window is closed. When this "About" window is closed, I would like to be able to display it again by clicking the "About" button again.

The problem in the current code: when the window "About" is displayed on the screen, I can activate the 2 buttons of the main form with the mouse, and because of this, I display as much windows "About" that I click on this button.

I tried the function "ShowDialog", but it does not work. I do not know how to do ? Thank you for helping me.

```
'About button.
Private Sub ButtonAbout_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles ButtonAbout.Click
    WindowAbout.ShowDialog()
End Sub

'Close button to close the main window.
Private Sub ButtonClose_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles ButtonClose.Click
    Close()
End Sub
```

Comment: What you're doing does exactly what you say you want. `ShowDialog` displays a modal dialogue, which prevents access to the caller.  If it's not working for you then something is broken. I suggest that you try the same thing in a new project and see if it works there.  If it doesn't then is a system issue and you may need to reinstall something.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I will try "ShowDialog" in a new project.
However, in my research, I noticed that other users were having the same problem with "ShowDialog".

Comment: After control, "ShowDialog" works well. I was facing a "Bug" system.
For information: to close the "About" window, I used Hide () instead of Close (), because when I use Close (), I can not open the "About" window again.
Under Hide () I can open and close the child window as many times as necessary because it is not closed but hidden.
Concerning the main window it is necessary to use Close ().

Comment: You can close and open a form as many items as you like calling `ShowDialog` and `Close`. When you call `Close` on a form that was displayed using `Show`, the form is disposed and cannot be shown again, so a new instance is required. Even if you use the default instance, it's still a different object that is shown each time. If you called `ShowDialog` though, even calling `Close` won't dispose the form so it can be redisplayed as many times as you like. Whatever problem you have, it's not the problem you think you have.

Comment: Yes, ShowDialog works well on the Windows Forms system, but under the WPF system, ShowDialog does not work.
I get this error:
"unhandled exception -> System.InvalidOperationException:
you can not call ShowDialog after closing a Window object."
That's why I use "Hide" to close (actually hide) the window.
If not, do you know how to handle this problem?

Comment: Ah, I didn't realise that it was a WPF app. That's why you should always add all appropriate tags to a question. You didn't say WinForms either but most people will assume WinForms before WPF because that's where the majority of people start and that's where the majority of work is still done. You do say "window" in a number of places but you also start by saying "form", so that probably primed me for WinForms. Your code does use `RoutedEventArgs` but I just didn't notice that. If you state that it's WPF with a tag then there can be no confusion.

Comment: There's still no problem though. Just create a new instance each time. That's what is usually done with forms or windows anyway, so why fight it? The only reason you might try to avoid it is if you want the state to remain the same between displays but, in that case, all you need is an object that stores the state that you can use in each instance.

Comment: Thank you for this information. To better understand your advice, how do you create this new instance allowing me to open and close the "About" window several times? In the following code (WPF System), the code only allows you to open it once.

Comment: If you need to create a new instance each time you call `ShowDialog`, you need to put the code that creates a new instance somewhere that it will get executed every time you call `ShowDialog`. Where do you suppose that would be?

Answer (score 0):

jmcilhinney, thanks for your advices.
After searching, here is the answer: add WindowAbout = New FormAbout.
Now it's OK.

```
'Window Main

Class MainWindow
    Dim WindowAbout As FormAbout = New FormAbout
    Private Sub Button_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
        WindowAbout = New FormAbout
        WindowAbout.ShowDialog()
    End Sub
End Class

--------

'Window About

Imports System.ComponentModel

Public Class FormAbout
    Private Sub Button_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
        Close()
    End Sub
End Class
```